# Simple window shadow/freeze between registration steps with spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Basically, i have a 4 steps registration process.
4 .html with 4 forms each one. Since you click next step in step one until you reach the step two it takes abouts 5 to 10 secs (it depends on the server...)

I want to shadow the window (and prevent users clicks etc etc) and show a spinner (to represent load process) while the transition to step two occurs.

In the site i have already colobox.js and jquery.js, I supose that it must be a jquery pluging tha accomplish perfectly the need or similar.

Any suggestion o pluggin or code sinppet??

Thanks in advice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [jquery-loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/).

With it, you can start masking with:

```
$("#mydiv").mask("Loading...");
```

The loading text optional, if you leave it out, it will just mask without displaying a message. Unmasking is just as easy:

```
$("#mydiv").unmask();
```

Here are some other options that I'm not as familiar with:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/loading
- http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/